# Is there any way to get the number of satellite without LocationProvider?

Tags: android, google-play, location-client, location-provider

I'm using `LocationClient` (a part of Google Play service) to get the current location. It works well, but I can't find any way to get the number of satellites without using `LocationProvider`.

```
mService_NORMAL = new LocationProvider(mParent, 10000, 1, 1);
mService_NORMAL.setupSatelliteCounter();
mService_NORMAL.setOnSatelliteChangeListener(this);
```

I don't want to use `LocationProvider` to get the number of satellites because my `LocationClient` has given me my location, so I also want to get the number of satellites from it.